# Why is Chrome issuing a "Confirm Form Resubmission" even when I'm using the PRG pattern?

Tags: php, google-chrome

After processing a POST request I am doing the very standard thing of redirecting to the same page so that the user won't get a "Confirm Form Resubmission" (or equivalent) dialog if they reload the page.

I am using a 303 response status code.

Here's the code:

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" );
header( "Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
exit();
```

This works as expected in Safari and FF. Chrome pops up the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog.

In Chrome I can use the network inspector to see that the 303 redirect is indeed issued and there is a GET following my  initial POST.

Yet if I try to reload the page at that point I get the "Confirm Form Resubmission".

If I modify the URL by adding a spurious query param, this does not happen. That is...

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" );
header( "Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?foo' );
exit();
```

...works just fine.

Is Chrome trying to be too clever and short-cutting the reload of the same page? Or is this a known issue? I've spent some time looking around, but aside from a million cases of people just needing to use the PRG pattern, nothing.

Comment: Chrome has a lot of very curios redirection handling. Maybe 307 (or 302) is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, but 307 repeats the same request so it causes a redirect loop.

Comment: I don't know, why this should be a problem, but you can always use 302.

Comment: Sadly 302 has the same problem as 303.

Comment: http://demo.sperke.net/postredirect.php (with 302) - no problems in Chromium 24 // Edit 307 causes problems, but 302 works (303 either).

Comment: The first time I ran your demo on Chrome it was using a 307 and there was an infinite redirect loop. The second time it was a 302 and I got the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog when I tried to reload the page.

Comment: Yeah I changed the code, to try out. But there is no dialog, when I use Ctrl+R or F5 - with 303 and 302.

Comment: I do see the dialog with Chrome 25.0.1364.99 (on OS X ML). Thanks for setting up that page though. Demonstrates the problem.

Comment: So we need a third opinion. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Chrome 25. I tested it in virtualbox with Chrome 24 and updated to Chrome 25.

Chrome 24 => No dialog

Chrome 25 => Dialog

Maybe you should file a bug. :-)

Comment: There is a bug filed already. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21245 . I should have checked there first I guess. :-/

Comment: Seems as this bug has reappeared. There are no problems in Chrome 24!? That's what i meant with curios header handling. :-)

Comment: I filed a new bug for it, as I think, they are not related https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177855

Comment: It might have been fixed and then regressed in 25. Either way the new bug is probably a good idea.

Comment: Nope, the bug 21245 is also present in 24 :-) … curios head … I think, I said that before. ;-)

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing what "curios" means. :-)

Comment: Curious in the meaning of strange. There are a lot of stupid behaviours in Chrome, e. g. in the caching of redirects.

Comment: I think this has been fixed in the current version, 26. (Just updated now).

Comment: It's still a bug on 33

Answer (score 0):

You can try proxy-redirect to script with different URI

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      header('Location: proxy.php?uri='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 303);
}
```

then come back

```
# proxy.php

if (!empty($_GET['uri'])) {
    // maybe some validation here
    header('Location: '.$_GET['uri'], true, 303);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user tries to restore the pages which have been unexpectedly shut down, then the browser will display this error 'err_cache_miss'. Watch the video proof for main source of the error 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c9ztzqlthE

Answer (score -1):

this will help you more better way
just put this in any file that include all files

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

---

if not then try this

```
session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate');
session_cache_expire(60);
```